# Combine and open multiple xml files in single Excel file

Tags: c#, xml, excel

Currently I have done to open an xml file in MS Office Excel.
But now I would like to open several xml files in single MS Office Excel in single sheet. (Means there are several file path of xml files)

Is it possible to do so without saving another new file? (I just want to open and display to user)

I have tried to write the codes with different file path but ends up with 2 excel files are opening at the same time.

I have done so many researches but unfortunately I cant find any articles that meet my requirements. I really need help so only will post at here. Thanks.

My codes behind:

```
var application = new Excel.Application();
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
application.Workbooks.OpenText(
                    filePath,
                    missing,
                    1,
                    missing,
                    Excel.XlTextQualifier.xlTextQualifierNone,
                    missing,
                    missing,
                    missing,
                    true,
                    missing,
                    missing,
                    missing,
                    missing,
                    missing,
                    missing,
                    missing,
                    missing,
                    missing
                    );
```

Comment: Can you explain further what you are wanting to do. Do you want to show each file in a new worksheet or append the imported xml to the current sheet.

Comment: I have a list of xml files for user to choose from. if user chose more than 1 xml file, it should open up 1 excel file with each file in new sheet to display all data. (all xml has the same architecture)

Comment: Ok, yes it is possibls to do what you want.  Instead of opening an new application for each file you need to create a new worksheet.  Also there is an `Workbooks.OpenXML` method that may be of use as well.

Comment: @NathanFisher do you mind to give me some pieces of code regarding this?

Comment: I will see what I can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by using the codes below.
filePath is the List that contains all the file path of selected xml file.

```
string fileToOpen = filePath[0].ToString();
string tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
if (filePath.Count > 1)
{
     XDocument merged = new XDocument(new XElement("root"));
     for (int i = 0; i < filePath.Count; i ++)
     {
         XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filePath[i]);
         merged.Root.Add(XDocument.Load(filePath[i]).Root);
     }
     merged.Save(tempFile);
     fileToOpen = tempFile;
}

var application = new Excel.Application();
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
application.Workbooks.OpenText(
                    fileToOpen,
                    missing,
                    1,
                    missing,
                    Excel.XlTextQualifier.xlTextQualifierNone,
                    missing,
                    missing,
                    missing,
                    true,
                    missing,
                    missing,
                    missing,
                    missing,
                    missing,
                    missing,
                    missing,
                    missing,
                    missing
                    );
```